# Flutter command not working after running "flutter upgrade"

Tags: flutter, macos

I recently tried running `flutter upgrade` and it seemed to run successfully. But after that the flutter command itself stopped working. Every time I try to run a flutter command it gives this error

```
'sysctl -n hw.optional.arm64' returned unexpected output: ''
```

I'm using a MacBook Pro with an Intel i7 processor.

I couldn't find anything on this error online. I also tried doing a git reset and a git pull on the flutter (core) directory. Nothing seems to help.

What could the issue be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it. For some reason after upgrading flutter the path variable got messed up, at least in my .zshrc file. So I had to go and add the `usr/sbin` path to the `PATH` variable. That's where the `sysctl` program sits and that's why it was giving an error that the output is empty.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: please explain more about this!
already usr/sbin path added in path variable.
still got the same error!!

Comment: I forgot what it was exactly but I just added the `usr/sbin` to the PATH variable and it started working. I probably restarted the system or something. Try `sysctl` in terminal and see if it give you the sysctl usage help. If it does then the PATh variable should be fine

Comment: I solved it by removing flutter SDK and downloading the latest SDK and installing it.

Comment: That's nice. Flutter creates path issues quite often. Even recently I had to re-install flutter and the flutter path was lost.